# How to return a nested object from a meteor helper

Tags: meteor, spacebars

If the database object has the form:

```
{ CampYear: 'ssipc16',
  FullName: 'Jane Doe',
  Lessons: { 
              Week1: 
                     { 
                       Monday: 3, 
                       Tuesday: 4, 
                       Wednesday: 5
                     }
            }
}
```

and I wanted to return from a helper the value of Monday under Week1 in Lessons to get 3, I'm not sure of the correct way to do that. I tried object notation:

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  someFunction: function () {
    return Lessons.Week1.Monday;
  }
});
```

And in the template:

```
<template name="someName">
  <div>
    <p>{{someFunction}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: `this.Lessons.Week1.Monday`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: You can do it straight in Blaze as well, `{{this.Lessons.Week1.Monday}}`

Comment: .. and there you can even drop the `this` if you want: {{Lessons.Week1.Monday}}